# Attempt to assign property "status" on null

Tags: php, arrays, php-8.1

I have the following code running on PHP 7.4.2, but after the update to PHP 8.1.2, I'm getting an error in order to fill an array with some data.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $myObj->status = '1';
    $myObj->video = $row["token"];
    $title = str_replace(".mp4","",$row["filename"]);
    $myObj->title = $title;
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "status" on null

Is this problem related to some change in PHP 8? I've tried to find some answers but have no success on how I can update the code to run in this new scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create `$myObj` before you can assign to `$myObj->status`.

```
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $myObj = new StdClass;
    $myObj->status = '1';
    $myObj->video = $row["token"];
    $title = str_replace(".mp4","",$row["filename"]);
    $myObj->title = $title;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a object of class without declaring it before which means that you need to tell PHP by declaring it outside the while loop.

```
class YourClassName{
 public $status; 
 public $video; 
 public $title; 
}

$myObj = new YourClassName; 
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $myObj = new StdClass;
    $myObj->status = '1';
    $myObj->video = $row["token"];
    $title = str_replace(".mp4","",$row["filename"]);
    $myObj->title = $title;
}
```

Comment: Why need to declare $myObj twice? Thanks